# Find records with exact matches on a many to many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three tables that look like these:

**PROD**

```
Prod_ID|Desc
------------
P1|Foo1
P2|Foo2
P3|Foo3
P4|Foo4
...
```

**RAM**

```
Ram_ID|Desc
------------
R1|Bar1
R2|Bar2
R3|Bar3
R4|Bar4
...
```

**PROD_RAM**

```
Prod_ID|Ram_ID
------------
P1|R1
P2|R2
P3|R1
P3|R2
P3|R3
P4|R3
P5|R1
P5|R2
...
```

Between **PROD** and **RAM** there's a Many-To-Many relationship described by the **PROD_RAM** table.

Given a `Ram_ID` set like `(R1,R3)` I would like to find all the `PROD` that has exactly *ONE* or *ALL* of the `RAM` of the given set.

Given `(R1,R3)` should return for example `P1`,`P4` and `P5`; `P3` should not be returned because has `R1` and `R3` but also `R2`.

What's the fastest query to get all the `PROD` that has exactly *ONE* or *ALL* of the `Ram_ID` of a given `RAM` set?

**EDIT:**
The `PROD_RAM` table could contain relationship bigger than 1->3 so, "hardcoded" checks for count = 1 OR = 2 are not a viable solution.

Comment: +1 to ask clear and understandable question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution you could try for speed would be like this

```
;WITH CANDIDATES AS (
    SELECT  pr1.Prod_ID
            , pr2.Ram_ID
    FROM    PROD_RAM pr1
            INNER JOIN PROD_RAM pr2 ON pr2.Prod_ID = pr1.Prod_ID
    WHERE   pr1.Ram_ID IN ('R1', 'R3')
)
SELECT  *
FROM    CANDIDATES
WHERE   CANDIDATES.Prod_ID NOT IN (
            SELECT  Prod_ID
            FROM    CANDIDATES
            WHERE   Ram_ID NOT IN ('R1', 'R3')
        )
```

or if you don't like repeating the set conditions

```
;WITH SUBSET (Ram_ID) AS (
    SELECT  'R1'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'R3'
)   
, CANDIDATES AS (
    SELECT  pr1.Prod_ID
            , pr2.Ram_ID
    FROM    PROD_RAM pr1
            INNER JOIN PROD_RAM pr2 ON pr2.Prod_ID = pr1.Prod_ID
            INNER JOIN SUBSET s ON s.Ram_ID = pr1.Ram_ID    
)
, EXCLUDES AS (
    SELECT  Prod_ID
    FROM    CANDIDATES
            LEFT OUTER JOIN SUBSET s ON s.Ram_ID = CANDIDATES.Ram_ID
    WHERE   s.Ram_ID IS NULL
)
SELECT  *
FROM    CANDIDATES
        LEFT OUTER JOIN EXCLUDES ON EXCLUDES.Prod_ID = CANDIDATES.Prod_ID
WHERE   EXCLUDES.Prod_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: @systempuntoout - now you got me wondering... and the second?

Comment: Could you explain a bit how these queries work?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Prod_ID
FROM 
  ( SELECT Prod_ID
         , COUNT(*) AS cntAll
         , COUNT( CASE WHEN Ram_ID IN (1,3)
                       THEN 1
                       ELSE NULL
                  END 
                ) AS cntGood
    FROM PROD_RAM
    GROUP BY Prod_ID
  ) AS grp
WHERE cntAll = cntGood
  AND ( cntGood = 1
     OR cntGood = 2               --- number of items in list (1,3)
      )
```

Not at all sure if it's the fastest way. You'll have to try different ways to write this query (using `JOIN`s and `NOT EXISTS` ) and test for speed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be something like the following:

```
SELECT PROD.Prod_ID FROM PROD WHERE

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PROD_RAM WHERE PROD_RAM.Prod_ID = PROD.Prod_ID) > 0 AND

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PROD_RAM WHERE PROD_RAM.Prod_ID = PROD.Prod_ID AND PROD.Ram_ID <> 
IFNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Ram_ID FROM PROD_RAM WHERE PROD_RAM.Prod_ID = PROD.Prod_ID),0)) = 0
```